# java project can not run inorder in the IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have module A and module B,and B required A, in the past,A Always run first,but now B runs before A,so it always throw exception,because A is not running yet,how can I fix that,thanks for looking

Comment: How are you expressing the relationship between the modules? How do you run them?

Comment: thanks for read,but I find the problem is in otherway,and i solve it finally